# UISwitch has an outline when changing the background color

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch, cornerradius

I've defined a switch as below:

```
self.toggleSwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.redColor;
self.toggleSwitch.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor;
self.toggleSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = self.toggleSwitch.frame.size.height / 2;
self.toggleSwitch.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

This is the result I'm getting: [image: Switch OFF] [image: Switch ON]

As can be seen in the images, there is an outline of the yellow background.
How this can be solved?

Comment: Have you added the toggle switch directly to the storyboard? Or have you created it programatically?

Comment: @JimTierney programmatically

Comment: Toggle button can not be modified. Use a custom switch.

Comment: Have you called `sizeToFit`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH didn't help.

Comment: Before setting corner radius?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I now called it from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it solved the issue.
Please can you phrase an answer?